# how to modify return value with panic and recover in golang

Tags: go

I have a problem
how to modify return value with panic and recover in golang
please help me, thank you!

```
func foo1() int {

    defer func() {
        if p := recover(); p != nil {
            fmt.Printf("internal error: %v\n", p)
        }
        // how can I do?
    }()

    panic("test error")
    return 10
}
```

Answer (score 14):

one way to do it is naming the return value in the func definition

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo() (r int) {
    defer func() {
        if p := recover(); p != nil {
            fmt.Printf("internal error: %v\n", p)
            r = 5 // this modify the return value
        }
    }()

    panic("test error")
    return 3
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo()) // this print 5
}
```

Comment: What a nice trick. I didn't know you can declare return var name when defining function.